# (Please see the image) would this be called "leaning against a table" or is there a better phrase for it?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when you sit like this on a table?

[image]

"Leaning against the edge of the table"?

Or is there a better alternative? (I'm sure there must be)

Comment: When A _leans_ on B, I think of it as A is supported only _laterally_ by B, it is not supported from _underneath_.

Comment: Almost irrelevantly, 'leaning on…' might be a better alternative…

Please note that 'Almost irrelevantly' is the operative phrase, not 'better…'

Answer (score 17):

He’s not sitting, exactly; his butt is not fully engaged in the activity. When this happens, we might use the word *perch*.

> *He is perched on the edge of the table. He perched himself on the edge of the table.*

From [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required):

> **perch**, *v.<sup>1</sup>*
> **II.** Senses related to PERCH *n.<sup>1</sup>* 6.
> **3.** *intransitive*. Of a bird: to alight or settle on a perch; to roost. Hence of a person or animal: to sit, stand, or rest, esp. in an
> elevated or somewhat precarious position. Also in extended use.
> **4. a.** *transitive* (*reflexive*). To sit or position oneself in an elevated or somewhat precarious position.

Selected sample usages:

> <sub>2001    C. GLAZEBROOK *Madolescents* 193    A
> few arty-farty types are perching on bar stools drinking beer or fancy
> coffee.</sub>
>  <sub>1913    *Sat. Evening Post*
> (Philadelphia) 22 Feb. 5/1    Perching himself on the
> hydrant, young Rosenstein read without further interruption.</sub>
> <sub>2001    Z. MOHYEDDIN in M. Shamsie *Leaving Home* 225
>    She perched herself on a big settee.</sub>

Explains [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/perch): If you perch on something, you sit down lightly on the very edge or tip of it: *He lit a cigarette and perched on the corner of the desk.*

Here are more samples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

<sub>Bianca’s English teacher perches on the edge of a desk, open book in hand.</sub>
<sub>She offered me a chair and perched on the edge of the sofa, watching me expectantly.</sub>
<sub>Bernard perches on the edge of the bench, blinking at Mr. B.</sub>
<sub>“She’s never been a fashion victim,” says Kors, perching on the edge of an enormous Louis-style desk.</sub>

See more samples there at [`perch* on the edge`](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=113547793).

<sub>For fun:
 [Ergo Impact — Is Perching the New Sitting? Research Suggests Yes.](https://ergoimpact.com/blogs/news/is-perching-the-new-sitting-research-suggests-yes)
[Young man perched on edge of desk, view through open patio doors - stock photo](https://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/young-man-perched-on-edge-of-desk-view-through-open-royalty-free-image/200431150-001)</sub>

Comment: OED's definition defines "perch" as "To sit or position oneself in an elevated or somewhat precarious position", so I don't know how he’s not sitting. He _is_ sitting. Moreover, in order for you to use "perch", he must be "in an elevated or somewhat precarious position", which I don't think he is. Note that he looks comfortable in that position with his feet firmly on the ground and even his hands on the table. So he's neither likely to fall nor in a precarious position.

Comment: I'd associate perching with legs dangling off the bottom and not in contact with the floor. You perch on high things.

Comment: @JK2 — Did I say he was not sitting? I said he was not sitting, exactly. That means he’s sort of sitting, and there is a word for that. For doubters, I have added a learner’s definition, as well as more samples from the corpus.

Comment: Why did you use the form _He is perched on..._ and _He perched himself on..._ instead of _He is perching on..._? And if you're to say _He is perching on the edge of the table_, why not say simply _He is sitting on the edge of the table_? I mean, what additional meaning apparent in OP's picture that cannot be conveyed by the latter can be conveyed by the former?

Comment: @JK2 — Just in time for Easter... If you *sit* on an edge, you get hot cross buns.

Comment: This is exactly correct, cf. 'perch seat', 'perch bench' etc.

Comment: "he is perched on the edge of the table" —— this means he is squatting on top of the table on his tiptoes like a gargoyle

Comment: @theonlygusti — Native English speakers beg to differ, as you can see from the corpus.

Comment: I agree "perched" is fine. When channel  5 launched in the UK the news reader Kirsty Young was often described as "perched on the desk" when pretty much in the same pose as the picture in the OP (was a novelty then as previously newsreaders would be sat behind the desk). e.g. https://vimeo.com/471449024

Answer (score 16):

To me it looks like he's **sitting on the edge of the table**.
I'm pretty sure most of his weight is resting vertically on his butt, because otherwise, the table would've slid back being pushed by his weight sideways and the guy would be lying on the floor by now.

Comment: Looks like the table already slid back.  Maybe, that's his second attempt.

Comment: "He sat on the edge of the table" is definitely the best

Answer (score 9):

A man **half-sitting** on a table.

**OED**

> **Half** *(adv.)* **1.** To the extent or amount of half. Hence more generally: in part, **partially; to a certain extent, in some degree.**
>
> **c. Modifying a present participle,** e.g. *half-comprehending, half-dreaming, half-joking, half-laughing, half-sleeping, half-smiling, half-waking.*
>
> 1762   W. Cole Let. 16 May in H. Walpole Corr. (1937) I. 7   *The lady lies in an half-reclining posture, with her head on a cushion..as though she was asleep.*
>
> 1817   S. T. Coleridge Biographia Literaria 223   *In one of his half-earnest, half-joking moods.*
>
> 2004   New Yorker 12 Apr. 90/1   *The movie reveals the sordidness of adult behavior as it appears to half-comprehending but pure-hearted children.*

Answer (score 8):

Google images for “resting against a table.”

This gives you many similar poses and some different ones.
But Googling images for “leaning against a table” brings up similar images.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rest+against

> rest against (someone or something)

> 1. To lean or recline against someone or something; to be propped lightly against someone or something else.

Answer (score 7):

This can certainly be called "leaning against the table."

I think it's a very accurate description of the picture. It captures the feeling well too. Leaning is lazy, relaxed, suave.

> He lent back against the table and flashed her a debonair smile

"Leaning" might connote that most of his weight supported by the table is going through his hands instead of his butt.

A more accurate adjective describing his pose is "half-sitting", and the best phrase to describe this position altogether is "sat on the edge of the table", or perhaps particularly "sat against the edge of the table".

Comment: Part of the problem with some of the other alternatives is that they are too stilted or formal for most contexts.

Comment: +1 for "leaning against the table" being perfectly correct, and also +1 for "sitting on the edge of the table", which is natural and unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

**Propped up against**

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prop%20up)

> Prop up **1:** to stop (something) from falling or slipping by placing something under or against it.

You could say the man propped himself up against the table. Much like ["half sat"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/605790/180914) it is too general to describe the picture in detail, and would need elaboration to convey details. Depending on how much of an essay you wanted to write you could say

> He propped himself up against the table, took most of the weight off his legs, and looked rightwards...

Comment: "propped up" is generally used for inanimate objects. If you told me a man was propped-up somewhere, I'd assume he was dead or unconscious. If you say he propped himself up I'd assume he was very, very drunk.

Comment: @OwenReynolds I take your point for general usage but it what came to mind when looking at the picture, before noticing the pubic bones were resting on the table.  FWIW I find "perched" would generally indicate that, like birds, both feet would be on the table. Personally  I would go with "he sat on the edge of the table(, dangling his feet on the ground)" and voted accordingly.

Comment: @traktor [me too](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605778/please-see-the-image-would-this-be-called-leaning-against-a-table-or-is-ther/605918#comment1529158_605780)

Comment: He propped his butt on the table, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you sit and lift your legs, you'd probably stay in place.
If you're perched/leaning and (try to) lift your legs, you'd not stay in place.
Hence the difference between sitting and perched/leaning.

Comment: So what phrase would you used to describe this position?